# How do Node Modules get added when deploying after pulling project from GitHub

Tags: laravel

I have never deployed a Laravel app before and am trying to figure something out.

I have a project that has Node Modules. Of course, when I push to Github, the Node Modules are not included. I have seen some videos on YouTube where someone uses Forge and pulls their GIthub project which doesn't include their Node Modules. Forge automatically runs composer install and runs the migrations. But, they never run npm install. I must be missing something. How do the Node Modules get into the deployed project?  Or, are the Node Modules simply used to compile the assets and therefore are not needed on the production server?

Comment: Just commit the package.json file and the other person will do the `npm install`. On the production server there are a lot of ways of doing it manually or Continuous Deployment using Jenkins or other tools.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that means the node modules are included on the production server.  What is confusing to me is that every tutorial I see shows the developer running a script with 'composer install' when setting up the server but never running npm install

Comment: `composer install` is the PHP/Laravel version of that, and uses `composer.json`, related to the `vendor` folder.

Comment: Btw, it is possible to add a composer post-install script in your composer.json, so that whenever you run `composer install`, it also runs `npm install`. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts.

Comment: composer and npm are different things. Please do a google search and you will get more answers.